# Squeak smalltalk: Drawing a morph representing a card suit

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I need to draw a morph representing a card suit symbol or a card from a playing cards deck.

I was thinking to use the TextMorph and [unicode characters for playing cards or suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode), but can't find any example how to build a string from unicode characters and to display it properly in TextMorph.

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from an expert, but this seems to go into the direction you want:

```
| aceOfDiamonds myTextMorph |
aceOfDiamonds := 16r1F0C1 asCharacter asString.
myTextMorph := TextMorph new newContents: aceOfDiamonds.
myTextMorph openInHand.
```

Now you can put this (editable) text morph somewhere, and its text will *contain* the character , but it will only display as a question mark. You might be able to change to a font that does display this correctly.

We can verify that the text does contain the correct character:

```
myTextMorph text asArray collect: [:c| c asUnicode].
```

prints `#(127169)`.

Comment: Yes. I cannot find any clear documentation on how exactly to load system fonts into Squeak, only suggestions it might be possible. The code as given works for me in Pharo if I change its default font to an appropriate system font (DejaVu Sans, in my case; I just looked at what font StackOverflow uses and picked that).

Comment: OK, here is how to add system fonts to Squeak: https://github.com/HPI-SWA-Teaching/Scamper/wiki/How-to-install-a-font-inside-Squeak-and-use-it-to-display-websites-with-Scamper, but even if I add the same font that works fine in Pharo, I also only get a question mark.